# How do i make my java program wait until there is entered a value into the textfield

Tags: java, jframe

Basically im trying to make a program that needs a barcode which you should enter through the GUI, it works with nextLine() since it pauses and waits for an input ,and i was wondering if there is anything like that but waiting for a input in a gui?

Comment: ActionListener on jTextField wouldn't be enough? Or make button and after click getText() from jTextField.

Comment: Can you give more details please ? how is your program designed ? code snippets can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to press after entering the input and listen to the button event. Check below example

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      JTextField textField = new JTextField("enter input");

      JButton button = new JButton();
      button.setText("Ok");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
              textField.getText());

        }
      });

      panel.add(textField);
      panel.add(button);

      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setSize(150, 100);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

The other option is adding a document listener to your text field.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            textField.getText());
      }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            textField.getText());
      }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            textField.getText());
      }

    };
    textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);

    frame.setSize(250, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```